# ArcGIS Geoprocessing Service results updates

Tags: service, task, progress, arcgis

I am trying to run a long (processing multiple objects) and heavy processing operation through ArcGIS Geoprocessing Service. It is working fine in execute synchronous or asynchronous operation, however, I would like to get the status update messages while geoprocessor is executing and show them as progress using ArcGIS silverlight or ArcGIS flex client.

I would appreciate if anyone can provide a clue, any literature or poc in this regard. In advance, I thank you all for your time and support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to it and you can find the details at url 'http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/89581-ArcGIS-Geoprocessing-Service-results-updates-as-porgress'. I hope it helps those looking for similar matters.